# How to define an integral of specific form

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory, definite-integrals

Suppose that $\theta(\cdot)$ is a function and it holds that $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\theta(x)=\theta^{'}(x)$ and
$$\theta^{-}= \max(0,-\theta)$$
in order to define the following integral
$$\int_{0}^{b}(\theta^{-}(x))^{'}dx$$

where $b$ is finite, what are the assumptions that we need to do about the function $\theta(\cdot)$ and why?

Comment: Is $\theta '(x)$ just $\frac{d\theta}{dx}$?

Comment: Yes, this is what i am writing in the assumptions, i.e. $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\theta(x)=\theta^{'}(x)$

Comment: Let me simplify it more

Comment: does it hold that $\int_{0}^{b}(\theta^{-}(x))^{'}dx=-\int_{0}^{b}(\theta(x))^{'}dx$ ?